# WPF web browser control takes to long to load

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit, wpf-4.0

Hi I am developing a WPF application. 
 The web browser control  takes a long time to load the page. 
Is there a way to display some text before the page loads . The .[Documenttext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is not available is not available in WPF .

1) Is there a way to make the web browser control faster.

2) Is there a way to display some text before the page loads.

I am currently using visual studio 2010  and I am using the following code to navigate to the page

```
public Window3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window3_Loaded);
    }

    public void Window3_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com")));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could first call [NavigateToString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigatetostring.aspx) and pass in some initial HTML or simply [Navigate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee169602.aspx) to a local page, then try to go browse the other site.

Something like

```
webBrowser.NavigateToString(@"<html><body><h1>PageLoading</h1></body></html>");
```

or

```
webBrowser.Navigate(@"/index.html");
```